# How can I properly add CSS and JavaScript to an HTML document?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This very well might be a *very* stupid question.

I'm trying to add an empty CSS file, an empty JavaScript file and the jQuery library into the most basic of HTML files, as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Testing</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.3.js" />
  <script src="application.js" />
</head>
<body>
  <h1 class=test>This is a test! Hello, world!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

However, it doesn't work. The `h1` doesn't display in my browser when the `link` or any of the `script`s are present, but displays normally otherwise.

What am I doing wrong here? Why doesn't this work, and how can I make it work?

Thank you very much,

Eden.

Comment: may be `application.js` doing something... otherwise code seems fine.

Comment: Both it and the CSS file are empty. I edited for clarity.

Comment: @EdenLandau your script tag should not close it self, it should be like </script> see my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `<script>` tags cannot be self closing. Try changing them to look like `<script src="..." type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: Was thinking the same, it seems it depends on what version of html5 [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script)
But given the fact it's html5, I think it should do it.

Comment: @MisterJ - No, script tags may be unclosed, but they cannot be self-closed under any circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

two things. script tags should have an end tag.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.3.js" /></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="application.js" /></script>
```

Another thing, see if you are navigating to the right file. Assume that your directory tree is the next

```
directory
  |-yourHTMLpage.html
  |-jquery-2.0.3.js
  |-application.js
  \-theme.css
```

then the next will work

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.3.js" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="application.js" /></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
```

But in most recent standards, we are using a folder for css and js files, like the next

```
directory
  |-yourHTMLpage.html
  |-js
     |-jquery-2.0.3.js
     \-application.js
  \-css
     \-theme.css
```

Then you have to adapt the link,

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.0.3.js" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/application.js" /></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/theme.css">
```

Notice the "js/" addition for javascript files and "css/" addition for css files. HTML will navigate from its directory to the said file. But if the file isn't there as the source element is telling, then the page won't load the said file.

Answer (score 0):

Are the css and js files in the same folder as your html ?

To see what is wrong, try a developper console to see what requests are sent (Press 'F12' on chrome or install the firebug extension on Firefox). There should be a "Network" tab that shows what files are requested and if your browser does or doesn't find them.

Comment: If it doesn't find css and js, it will still display html.

Comment: What @MisterJ said. And yeah, they are.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the path to the several files is correct? If it is, is the class of the h1 spelled correctly?
You should embed the javascript files like this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.3.js"> </script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="application.js"> </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple method for include css and javascript file to your page.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="YOUR FILE PATH">
<script src="YOUR FILE PATH" type="text/javascript"></script>
```